# Android MVP. Testing View (Instrumental tests or unit test using Robolectric)

Tags: android, unit-testing, mvp

Have the following doubts about testing View (Activity, Fragment). The first approach is to test view using robolectric with mocking Android components like the following code do:

```
private void setUp() {
        fragment = new CustomFragment();
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
}
@Test
public void testOnCreateView() {
    fragment.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.from(activity), (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.container), null);
    verify(repoInfoPresenter).onCreateView(null);
}
```

Don't like this approach, cause this tests executing takes long time. In my opinion unit tests should be executed on each merge request, so they shouldn't be as slow as tests like that.

Another variant is to write Instrumentation tests using Espresso. I know that it's already takes long time and real device, but I don't think that this test should executed as often as tests running on jvm.

Or maybe there is magical variant to mock(make stubs) for fragments or Activities which I don't know about?